# MemoryError on database import in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, database, data-science

I'm trying to import the database and place the files one under the other

```
months = {'jan': 1, 'fev':2, 'mar':3, 'abr':4, 'mai':5, 'jun':6, 'jul':7, 'ago':8, 'set':9, 'out':10, 'nov':11, 'dez':12}

base_path = pathlib.Path('dataset')

base_airbnb = pd.DataFrame()

for file in base_path.iterdir():
    month_name = file.name[:3]
    month = months[month_name]
    
    year = file.name[-8:]
    year = int(year.replace('.csv', ''))
    
    df = pd.read_csv(base_path / file.name)
    df['year'] = year
    df['month'] = month
    base_airbnb = base_airbnb.append(df)

display(base_airbnb)
```

> is not aligned. A future version of pandas will change to not sort by
> default.
>
> To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.
>
> To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass
> 'sort=True'.

It appears that I have `MemoryError:`. But something goes wrong and I don't understand why... I'm sure I'm doing everything correctly in Jupyter Notebook

> To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.
>
> To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass
> 'sort=True'.
>
> sort=sort,

```
C:\Users\CASA\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3058: DtypeWarning: Columns (87) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.   interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-7-e9e45fb3206d> in <module>
     15     df['year'] = year
     16     df['month'] = month
---> 17     base_airbnb = base_airbnb.append(df)
     18 
     19 big_data=pd.concat(months, axis=0)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in append(self, other, ignore_index, verify_integrity, sort)    7121             ignore_index=ignore_index,    7122             verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
-> 7123             sort=sort,    7124         )    7125 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    253         verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
    254         copy=copy,
--> 255         sort=sort,
    256     )
    257 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in
__init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    333 
    334             # consolidate
--> 335             obj._consolidate(inplace=True)
    336             ndims.add(obj.ndim)
    337 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
_consolidate(self, inplace)    5268         inplace = validate_bool_kwarg(inplace, "inplace")    5269         if inplace:
-> 5270             self._consolidate_inplace()    5271         else:    5272             f = lambda: self._data.consolidate()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
_consolidate_inplace(self)    5250             self._data = self._data.consolidate()    5251 
-> 5252         self._protect_consolidate(f)    5253     5254     def _consolidate(self, inplace=False):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
_protect_consolidate(self, f)    5239         """    5240         blocks_before = len(self._data.blocks)
-> 5241         result = f()    5242         if len(self._data.blocks) != blocks_before:    5243             self._clear_item_cache()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in f()    5248    5249         def f():
-> 5250             self._data = self._data.consolidate()    5251     5252         self._protect_consolidate(f)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in consolidate(self)
    930         bm = self.__class__(self.blocks, self.axes)
    931         bm._is_consolidated = False
--> 932         bm._consolidate_inplace()
    933         return bm
    934 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in
_consolidate_inplace(self)
    935     def _consolidate_inplace(self):
    936         if not self.is_consolidated():
--> 937             self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
    938             self._is_consolidated = True
    939             self._known_consolidated = True

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in
_consolidate(blocks)    1911     for (_can_consolidate, dtype), group_blocks in grouper:    1912         merged_blocks =
_merge_blocks(
-> 1913             list(group_blocks), dtype=dtype, _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate    1914         )    1915         new_blocks = _extend_blocks(merged_blocks, new_blocks)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in
_merge_blocks(blocks, dtype, _can_consolidate)    3318         # combination of those slices is a slice, too.    3319         new_mgr_locs = np.concatenate([b.mgr_locs.as_array for b in blocks])
-> 3320         new_values = np.vstack([b.values for b in blocks])    3321     3322         argsort = np.argsort(new_mgr_locs)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py in vstack(tup)
    281     """
    282     _warn_for_nonsequence(tup)
--> 283     return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
    284 
    285 

MemoryError:
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the *full* MemoryError error message with traceback. The message in your question isn't complete.

Comment: As an aside, **don't do this in a loop: `base_airbnb = base_airbnb.append(df)`** That is highly inefficient, use a `list` then `pd.concat` it at the end

Comment: In any case, it sounds like you are running out of memory.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm running out of memory so would I stop importing the database?